# Insertar valores en una tabla usando PL/SQL tabla y procedimiento

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

He hecho un procedimiento en un paquete para introducir datos en una tabla utilizando una tabla PL/SQL y un Type Record.
He puesto algunos datos en el codigo para ejecutar desde el paquete y comprobar que funcione el procedimiento, pero no se como ejecutarlo desde la hoja de trabajo con los datos que yo introduzca.

```
CREATE TABLE TB_CRUD_MAC
   (    "K_CODIGO" NUMBER(10,0), 
    "A_NUMNIT" VARCHAR2(11 BYTE), 
    "N_NOMBRE" VARCHAR2(11 BYTE), 
    "N_APELLI" VARCHAR2(11 BYTE), 
    "F_FECHA" DATE, 
    "I_ESTADO" VARCHAR2(1 BYTE), 
    "K_CLASIF" VARCHAR2(1 BYTE)
   )
```

```
create or replace PACKAGE PK_CRUD_MAC AS

   TYPE R_REGISTRO IS RECORD (
     codigo TB_CRUD_MAC.K_CODIGO%TYPE := K_CODIGO.nextval,
     numnit TB_CRUD_MAC.A_NUMNIT%TYPE,
     nombre TB_CRUD_MAC.N_NOMBRE%TYPE,
     apelli TB_CRUD_MAC.N_APELLI%TYPE,
     fecha TB_CRUD_MAC.F_FECHA%TYPE,
     estado TB_CRUD_MAC.I_ESTADO%TYPE,
     clasif TB_CRUD_MAC.K_CLASIF%TYPE
     );

   TYPE T_REGISTRO IS TABLE OF R_REGISTRO;

   PROCEDURE PR_INSERT_LISTA (PT_REGISTRO IN OUT T_REGISTRO);   
END;
```

```
create or replace PACKAGE BODY PK_CRUD_MAC AS

    PROCEDURE PR_INSERT_LISTA (PT_REGISTRO IN OUT T_REGISTRO)

    IS

      BEGIN

      PT_REGISTRO := T_REGISTRO();
      PT_REGISTRO.extend(3);
      PT_REGISTRO(1).nombre :=  'Andres';
      PT_REGISTRO(2).nombre :=  'Martinez';

      INSERT INTO TB_CRUD_MAC VALUES (K_CODIGO.nextval, '123', PT_REGISTRO(1).nombre, 'AAA', '28/03/00', '1', '1');
      INSERT INTO TB_CRUD_MAC VALUES (K_CODIGO.nextval, '123', PT_REGISTRO(2).nombre, 'AAA', '28/03/00', '1', '1');

      END;

END;
```

Intente esto pero no ha funcionado:

```
DECLARE
reg PK_CRUD_MAC.T_REGISTRO := PK_CRUD_MAC.T_REGISTRO();
BEGIN
reg().extend;
reg(1).nombre := 'AAA';
PK_CRUD_MAC.PR_INSERT_LISTA(reg);
END;
```

Error: **PLS-00355: use of pl/sql table not allowed in this context**

Answer (score 0):

Descubri mi error y es asi corregido:

```
    DECLARE
    reg PK_CRUD_MAC.T_REGISTRO := PK_CRUD_MAC.T_REGISTRO();
    BEGIN
    reg.extend;
    reg(1).nombre := 'AAA';
    PK_CRUD_MAC.PR_INSERT_LISTA(reg);

END;
```